# Fragment within a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an ActionBar containing two tabs, Fragment A and Fragment B.

Is it possible to have Fragment A hold ANOTHER two fragments, Fragment C and Fragment D? Let's say I want Fragment A to initially show a button, which if clicked will transfer the user to a textview.

Is it possible to couch the button in Fragment C, the text in Fragment D, then contain both of these fragments in Fragment A? Can somebody provide a sample code how to replace Fragments INSIDE another Fragment on the click of a button? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it is only possible to have nested fragments since the version 4.2 (API 17).

Here is the details on the update:
http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments

Using this version you get new functions such as:

```
getParentFragment()
```

This function will allow you to reach directly the parent fragment from the current one.

Comment: please avoid this at all costs. You've seen inception, dreams within dreams / fragments within fragments, It all ends in a bad time and death

Comment: Haha; had to laugh at Blundell. I got your point, guys. Thank you. :)